# .htaccess causing 403 Access Denied in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a website for eg. www.example.com which has a custom .htaccess file designed to increase the site speed and make sure that the directory can't be listed.

I have a WordPress installed in the /blog directory i.e; www.example.com/blog/, the blog was working fine till the updated version of the website while after a span of a week the blog stops opening and started showing 403 Access denied. Tried every method available on google *I went to the second page of google too*.

After an hour I removed the .htaccess of the base directory and my blog is running up and fine again, I was a little curious to know if I will place the .htaccess file again what will happen and after I pushed it back to the server nothing happens to the WordPress site.

But I am afraid this can happen in the near future and hence I need to find out what part of my .htaccess is causing this problem. I still can't access wp-admin.

[image]

My .htaccess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/Error
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/Error
ErrorDocument 401 https://example.com/Error

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# START DEFLATE COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
"application/javascript" \
"application/json" \
"application/ld+json" \
"application/manifest+json" \
"application/rdf+xml" \
"application/rss+xml" \
"application/schema+json" \
"application/vnd.geo+json" \
"application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
"application/x-font" \
"application/x-font-opentype" \
"application/x-font-otf" \
"application/x-font-truetype" \
"application/x-font-ttf" \
"application/x-javascript" \
"application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
"application/xhtml+xml" \
"application/xml" \
"font/eot" \
"font/otf" \
"font/ttf" \
"font/opentype" \
"image/bmp" \
"image/svg+xml" \
"image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
"image/x-icon" \
"text/cache-manifest" \
"text/css" \
"text/html" \
"text/javascript" \
"text/plain" \
"text/vcard" \
"text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
"text/vtt" \
"text/x-component" \
"text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
"text/xml"
</IfModule>
# END DEFLATE COMPRESSION

# START ENABLE KEEP ALIVE
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
# END ENABLE KEEP ALIVE

# START EXPIRES CACHING #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES CACHING #


# DISABLE IMAGE HOTLINKIING START
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ â€“ [NC,F,L]
# DISABLE IMAGE HOTLINKIING END

# ENABLE MOD PAGESPEED START
# COMBINE CSS, COMPRESS IMAGES, REMOVE HTML WHITE SPACE AND COMMENTS
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
</IfModule>
# ENABLE MOD PAGESPEED END

# START â€“ Disable server signature #
ServerSignature Off
# END â€“ Disable server signature #

# ENABLE LITESPEED CACHE START
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
CacheEnable public
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET|HEAD$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login|admin|register|post|cron
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !nocache
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:max-age=300]
</IfModule>
# ENABLE LITESPEED CACHE END

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex Home.html
```

Comment: Your Apache server's error log will actually tell you what the problem is. You should look in there

Comment: There is no Apache server's error log, here I can only see cron job logs. Any idea where should I look at I followed up [these instructions](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583298-where-can-i-find-error-logs-for-my-website)

Comment: I can assure that the forbidden error is due to the base directory .htaccess as I removed it right now and everything is working fine without any forbidden error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a small mistake from my side in the end

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex Home.html
```

This code makes Home.html the default homepage of every directory and I haven't declared default page in the .htaccess file of WordPress, which is finding Home.html and as SecuPress is enabled he is blocking this request so I just added this code to .htaccess of WordPress folder

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

and everything worked fine as expected. *But I lost my WordPress theme and Plugins setting while finding this.SED.*